# How to render a value from app.js page to some html page in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

In the below code,I'm able to get the 'ip' value from a.html page.Now I want to send this ip value to text box field of b.html page using node.js.

My app.js:

```
   var ip;
    app.post('/retrieve',function(req, res, next){
      ip  =   req.body.client_ip;
    console.log(ip);
        });
```

How can I achieve this.Can anyone please suggest on this issue ...

Comment: If you use express you can write the value to the **res** like this: `res.mydata.ip = ip;` and read the value from the view, else you can write the value directly to the res stream like this `res.write(ip); res.end();`

Comment: Now I'm trying to use res.write(ip);res.end(); Then how to read the value from the html page.I want to read this ip value to the text box field of html page.

Comment: res.write already write the response (for your point if view is the page), is better to read some docs like [this hello node](http://howtonode.org/hello-node)

Comment: k fine thanks a lot for ur info

Comment: Actually now my data is in this url http://localhost:3000/retrieve.How to place this data as the value for text field of the html page.

Comment: Too broad to write here you must read some docs to better understand how node (and http or express module works)

Comment: k.Can u provide some links regarding this...

Comment: Start here [nodeschool](http://nodeschool.io/)

Comment: K thanks  a lot for ur info